# MASM: How to pass value by reference

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

I am trying to pass 2 variables to a procedure, add them together, and return and print the result. I am using the Stack Frame. I am not getting the right result, rather a large incorrect number. Thank you.

```
        INCLUDE PCMAC.INC


.MODEL SMALL
.586
.STACK 100h
.DATA
sum DWORD ?

.CODE
        EXTRN  GetDec :NEAR, PutDDec : NEAR, PutHex : NEAR
Main PROC
        _Begin
        push 10
        push 20

        call Test12

        ; Print result
        call PutDDec

        _Exit
Main ENDP
Test12 PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+12] ;
    add eax, [ebp+8] ;

    pop ebp
    ret 8
Test12 ENDP
End Main
```

Comment: Does `PutDDec` work if you just load `eax`? Have you used a debugger to check value in `eax`?

Comment: Yes ` mov eax, 10`  works fine for example

Comment: Does `push 10; pop eax` work fine too? Use a debugger and/or provide actual disassembly of your code.

Comment: Currently don't have a debugger to work with. Interesting... push 10; pop eax does not work but push 10; pop ax. I think there is an issue pushing as an word and receiving as a double word

Comment: Sounds like you are in 16 bit mode. If your environment is 32 bit then switch the assembler to 32 bit mode. If your environment is 16 bit then of course you need to use 16 bit code.

Comment: Cool beans, ty. I am using dosbox so that is probably the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Clear EAX register before pushing your data into stack.

```
    mov  eax,0
    push 10
    push 20

    call Test12
```

Comment: This cannot solve the issue! `mov eax,0` in no way has any influence on the subsequent `push 10` and `push 20`.